Migration SQL Server database object from one database to another
My client has software installed at hundreds of locations that uses a SQL Server database. Of course, everyone is on a different version of the software and thus the database as well.
At install time, we need to update the target database from a current version database. The current version db will have all the tables, columns, stored procedures, etc., and if any of these are missing from the target, we need to add them. In some cases when a new table moves, the data must move as well so we need a way to indicate this.
I know EF Migrations can do something similar. Is that the approach to take? We don't need to move any source code as the source will be updated already and we are installing a new EXE/DLL set at the client which needs to have whatever changes are needed to bring their db up to the current version.
What is the best way to handle this?

The best way to handle this, though you won't want to hear it, is to have one common database (cloud-based, perhaps?) that all clients connect to, so that you won't have this upgrade nightmare of hundreds of locations with different SQL Server installations. Just the annual licensing cost savings alone would make you the hero.

We use SQL Compare

Problem is, we can't use a cloud-based solution as the company doesn't want to maintain anything on the web. AS for SQL Compare, that's a great tool but it needs to be don individually. We're looking to have a utility that will run, do the compares, and make the adjustments

Sounds like migrations is the way to go. It's tricky stuff though, i don't know about how well EF does it but you really need to have good nerves and processes doing it manually, as well as handle errors correctly

I would imagine all the locations are connected by WAN, so why not one big on-premise SQL Server instance, on a server cluster with an Always On Availability Group utilizing 3 - 4 nodes? It would still be immensely cheaper than hundreds of SQL Server 2-core licenses.

Here's what I was thinking. Dump the source INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMN to an XML file along with another file containing all the index definitions and stored procs. We have no functions, views, triggers, or synonyms and we don't add users. Then, when the app starts up it looks for the XML file, compares it to the targets, and uses the deltas to make the changes (add new tables, columns, indexes or widen existing columns) and we're done. At that point, delete the XML file and its absence tells the app not to run the schema update again

The problem is, if you have version 1 adding colX, then populating it from colY, and in version 2 you rename colX to Z, then changing datatype in version 5 etc. This stuff is brutal.

EF migrations would be an answer... if the databases are already using EF migrations. EF migrations manage schema changes in incremental revisions, recording the history of changes in a table like __EFMigrationsHistory (this can be customized), but the databases will all need to be in a (standard) known state before starting to apply any migrations.

I prefer to use the tools that Microsoft provides, for these types of scenarios I use one called "Data Migration Assistant", it has worked very well for me in several migrations that I have done.
